# can't create outlet from storyboard to editor from a subview

Tags: iphone, uiview, storyboard, subview

Why can't I connect outlets from subviews?

- Dropped a `UIViewcontroller` onto **storyboard**
- Dropped a subview (`UIView`) as a custom class `CustomSubView` : `UIView`
- Went into Inspector while subview is selected and changed custom class to `CustomSubView`
- I have a couple of labels inside the subview

I tried to drag-drop from **storyboard** to assistant editor while `CustomSubView` class header is shown, but I don't get the pop-up to create the outlet. What gives?

I am using Xcode 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually write the `IBOutlet` property declaration in the `@interface` of the custom view subclass, and assuming you've defined the base class of your subview in IB, then you can drag from the outlet circle in the code back to the control in the scene.

It was answered here: [Cannot create outlet connections to subviews in Interface Builder (Xcode 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293989/cannot-create-outlet-connections-to-subviews-in-interface-builder-xcode-5)

or you can try this:

After typing the property outlet declarations manually in the customview.h file I could ctrl-drag-connect them from there to their corresponding UIlabel objects in the interfacebuilder. Works only in this direction!

Comment: Thank you. It looks to be a bug in Xcode IB. Once I get time I will try to find if its documented on OpenRadar.