# How to change Xib's label from UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

I have Xib UIView which is being displayed by my ViewController. The Xib contains an UILabel and an UIButton. My button coats all over my xib and i'm using it to navigate my SecondViewController and i achieve this by delegate methods.

Here's the thing about my label; because my button is transparent, i can show it beneath the button. What i can't do is to change mylabel's text from ViewController.

I did some search and come across a suggestion like this:

> is create another .nib file for the subview and put the subview in
>   there. Then in that .nib file, make the file owner IOSubview. Property
>   connections will work just fine there. Then just add the subview to
>   your IOViewController programatically. Just remember to load the nib
>   file from bundle first.
>
> link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20294118/1450201

But it doesn't make sense to me because the reason i created the xib at first is to use it more than once. I believe solution to this problem could be much simpler. But how??

This is what my xib looks like:
[image]

And here is a github repo link and my code:

https://github.com/TimurAykutYildirim/demoView

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Mini.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SelectionProtocol>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet Mini *miniView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *miniLabel;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.miniView.delegate = self;
}


-(void) isClicked {
    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Mini.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SelectionProtocol;

@interface Mini : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SelectionProtocol> delegate;

- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender;

@end


@protocol SelectionProtocol <NSObject>

@required
-(void) isClicked;

@end
```

Mini.m

```
#import "Mini.h"

@implementation Mini

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self load];
    }

    return self;
}


- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self load];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)load {
    UIView *view = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] loadNibNamed:@"Mini" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    [self addSubview:view];
    view.frame = self.bounds;

    //    ui component properties will be set here

}
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {

    if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SelectionProtocol)]) {
        [self.delegate isClicked];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: You need to create injection of UILabel into your UIView class, in your case in "Mini" class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Mini.h to add label outlet to it.

**Mini.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SelectionProtocol;

@interface Mini : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SelectionProtocol> delegate;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *miniLabel;

- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender;
@end


@protocol SelectionProtocol <NSObject>

@required
-(void) isClicked;

@end
```

and in ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.miniView.delegate = self;
    self.miniView.miniLabel.text = //set whatever value
}
```

Comment: thanks! i'll mark it as answer as soon as 5 min. rule complies of so